# How to Call ViewResult in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Dear Experts, 
I am following [Mr.Steve Sanderson Example][1] for working with variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style.

The code Below is adding New Items perfectly when we click on "Add More" hyperlink: -

I want instead of click on "Add More", make a function which do same as `$("#addItem").click` is doing and I call that function in my routine.

Can some one please guide me how can I do this?

**Controller Code: -**

```
  public ViewResult BlankEditorRow(string formId)
    {
        return new AjaxViewResult("ChequeDetail", new cheques()) { UpdateValidationForFormId = formId };
    }
```

**View Code: -**

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("Add More", "BlankEditorRow", new { ViewContext.FormContext.FormId }, new { id = "addItem" }) %>
```

**JQuery : -**

```
$("#addItem").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $("#editorRows").append(html);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it work with this line of code: -

```
            var a = document.getElementById('addItem');
        $(a).trigger('click');
```

Sorry if I was not expressed my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to do differently, do you want to add the click handler in your actionlink instead of with the jQuery you have now?

**View**

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Add More", "BlankEditorRow", new { ViewContext.FormContext.FormId }, new { id = "addItem", onclick="AddItem();" }) %>
```

**Javascript**

```
function AddItem()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $("#editorRows").append(html);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure what you want different, but if I got your question right you don't want to make click events for every link?

If that's so, you can do like this:

```
$.fn.addTo = function (element) {
  return this.each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {

      $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
          $(element).append(html);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

Now you just have to initialize this at startup of your project:

```
$('.addItem').addTo('.container');
```

and every link with class "addItem" will load it's href and append it to ".container". Maybe you have to change logic for appending to different containers, but hopefully you get the point :)

Comment: Kristoffer, you are right I dont want to add via click event instead I want automatically when my $("#ScanBCode").keyup(function (e) call inside the function there is else condition if else condition calls at that point I want to add new item.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the problem. Your function "AddNewRow" seems to fit perfectly inside your else-statement, because that's when you want to add a new row. Correct me if I', wrong.

Comment: yes but new item is not adding :( I dont know there is no error

Answer (score 0):

Okey, there is a problem with your code. You should never call a function without declaring it first. This means, your function "AddNewRow" should be written over your call.

Actually, I would just skip the function and do like this:

```
else {
     $.ajax({
          url: this.href,
          cache: false,
          success: function (html) {
               $("#editorRows").append(html);
          }
     });
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: First, I would change url to "yourControllerName/BlankEditorRow/" and secondly, if ".text-box-Area", ".text-box-Cons" etc are elements that gets returned from your ajax call, I would put them in your success function, since that's the callback function.